# Issue changing a word in a URL using mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to change the word "portfolio" in my URLs to "portfolio/project" and inadvertently created a redirect loop. Would appreciate any help in pointing me in the right direction.

Example:

http://www.example.com/portfolio/interactive/abc/ to

http://www.example.com/portfolio/project/interactive/abc/

Current htaccess (last two lines relates to issue):

```
redirect 301 "/sitemap.xml" http://www.example.com/sitemap.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sitemap.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /.*portfolio.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)portfolio(.*)$ /$1portfolio/project$2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your regex also matches your target, so after the redirect, the URI matches the same rule and gets redirected again (you may have noticed that there's a bunch of `/project/project/project/project/project/project/project` in the URI)

Add an exclusion condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !portfolio/project
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /.*portfolio.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)portfolio(.*)$ /$1portfolio/project$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: OK, thanks I think I follow, so the result is also a match creating a loop. So does the line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !portfolio/project` then prevent the result from being a match by excluding it?

Comment: @jsuissa Yeah, because the redirected URI is going to have `portfolio/project` in it, and the condition is only true if that string *isn't* in the URI.

Comment: Thanks...worked well...but oddly index.php is now back in the URLs: http://www.example.com/index.php/portfolio/project/interactive/abc/

Comment: @jsuissa you have to put the portfolio redirect *before* your index.php rule, because both rules are being applied, you just want to redirect and be done with it, not: *apply first index rule first, then apply portfolio redirect*